# Chromedriver.exe has stopped working - python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting this error:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chromedriver-crashes

I get it when running the command:

```
python Web.py
```

However when I go into the file and run the lines 1 by 1, I don't get the error. However I always get the error when the Web.py file has finished. When I run the lines 1 by 1, it's very basic things but i feel like I"m not ending my script correctly.

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('espn.com')
```

I want the window with espn.com to stay on the screen, not quit when the script has finished.

I'm running this on Python. I can share my setup, maybe that's something I did incorreclty but any help would be appeciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an invalid url.

You need to pass the url like this:

```
driver.get("http://www.espn.com")
```

This might work in your browser, but it won't with selenium. Type in "espn.com" in your browser and then copy / paste the url and you'll see that it's actually the above url.

You should also specify the "chromedriver.exe" path.

Comment: I don't know if that was right, using firefox successfully now

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you had not installed the chrome driver for selenium on your Machine. Selenium by default provides the driver for Firefox so when you use the webdriver for Firefox, it won't rise any error. To resolve this issue with Chrome you can download the Chrome webdriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

and you can specify the driver as

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<your Chrome driver path>')
```

Adding to what @Pythonista  said , it's better if you keep the URL as a raw string than a normal string

```
driver.get(r'http://www.espn.com')
```

so that it won't take the slash as an escape sequence in few cases.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update chrome and get updated/latest chrome driver, recently chrome made several updates in its driver you can download the last one from the link below:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.27/chromedriver_win32.zip